# You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details with new ChatGPT account?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

> a Few days back, I created an account with chat gpt. Now I have tried api the first time but it's giving me an error; my quota has finished. but I have not used it. even in the usage section, it's telling 0 calls so far. I still have full credit. I created an account 5 days ago. and created API key 24 hours ago.

```
import openai
import os

# Set up OpenAI API client

openai.api_key = 'string_key'
# model_engine = "curie" # choose a language model, for example 'davinci' or 'curie'
# model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo'

# Generate text with GPT
prompt = 'what is moon size'
response = openai.Completion.create(
engine='gpt-3.5-turbo',
prompt=prompt,
max_tokens=10,
n=1,
stop=None,
temperature=0.5,
 )
print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```

But I saw people creating it and using it. is it locked because of country restrictions? just like the Google Bard project only allowed in certain countries?

I have read a couple of questions about that [this_anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please). But my problem is its a new account and I am using it for the first time. So getting out of quota does not seem right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Comment: Thank you for your time. NO its not the same. That person has actually used his quota. That's why I specifically said Its a new account and i haven't used single request.

Comment: Is this your second OpenAI account?

Comment: So... _did_ you check your plan and billing details? Is everything set up on that end?

Comment: I am using without billing plan. I have not added my card details. I have 18$ in the granted section.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this concerns third-party product pricing and support (rather than how to write code for that product), which is off-topic for SO. Please see [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576/11107541) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/11107541) for more information. You should contact the company for up-to-date information about pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message. It seems you need to have a paid account to use the API. I set up a pay as you go account and it cleared that particular error ( now getting another! but there may be a error in my code ) . Looking around online it seems to be the case though. Also worth noting that once you sign up as pay as you go, you lose the $18 grant.