# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: Why do I still get the "You exceeded your current quota" error even though I set up a paid account (subscribed)?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

Why did I get `RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.`? I was subscribed, and this is my first request. I paid for my subscription.

Here is my code:

```
import openai
KEY = "mykeyhere it is checked over 10 times" //i tries to create new keys, not working, all times RATELIMITERROR
openai.api_key = KEY
def generate_response(text):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        prompt=text,
        engine='text-davinci-003',
        max_tokens=100,
        temperature=0.7,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        timeout=15
    )
    if response and response.choices:
        return response.choices[0].text.strip()
    else:
        return None

res = generate_response("Hello, how are you?")

print(res)
```

What did I do wrong, and why did my first request give this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Answer (score 3):

[Generate a new API key](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys) if your old API key was generated before you upgraded to the paid plan.

Comment: Does not help, any more trick ?

Comment: @l2aelba Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898717) answer entirely?