# OpenAI API key expired even though I haven't used it before?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

Am creating a website where I created a chatbot using chatgpt API key but it's not working (as u know openai gives $18 free trail API key to every user but it's showing expired even though I haven't used it for a single time before).. why?? If it's not going to work then do u now any other alternative than chatgpt API??

I have created new account's too to get api key but not working.

Comment: Did you ask their customer support for help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a new account then you should use a different phone number. If you use the same phone number that you had used for the previous account then you will not get the free credits.

Also, make sure you give a name to the organization field even though it is optional. In my case, I did not get the free credits when I had not added the organization. It was set to Personal by default. So, I updated it to my organization's name and then I got the free $5 credits.