# You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details

Tags: laravel, error-handling, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have an error. when i send request to chat gpt API to  generate responses. it give an error :

> "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details."

[image: Chat gpt error image] .

But i have created a new account. and there no single usages with that account.

i am expecting to provide solution.

Comment: Read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)