# openAI on mac os issue -- NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'

Tags: python, pycharm, openssl, urllib3, libressl

When I run the following code in pyCharm IDE:

```
import creds
import os
import openai

os.environ["OPENAPI_KEY"] = creds.API_KEY
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAPI_KEY"]

keep_prompting = True
while keep_prompting:
    prompt = input("Please enter in your question or prompt. Type exit if done. ")
    if prompt == "exit":
        keep_prompting = False
    else:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="text-davinci-003",
            prompt=prompt,
            max_tokens=200
        )
        print(response)
```

I get the following run-time error in the terminal window:

```
/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/bin/python /Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/chat.py 
/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py:34: NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(
Please enter in your question or prompt. Type exit if done. How does a chicken hatch from an egg?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/chat.py", line 14, in <module>
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  File "/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
  File "/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "/Users/studywithrue/PycharmProjects/chat/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 765, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the following are images of my pycharm python packages, and my current homebrew packages and pip packages.

[image]
[image]

I've been looking at several articles on this for the past hours and nothing works. tried re-installing urllib3 and openssl and nothing works for me on mac os. currently using a mid-2015 macbook pro and i have the latest OS.

Comment: Your error seems to be more of a quota issue rather than a code issue.   Are you certain you haven't overused your quota?

Comment: @ewokx this is my first time using chatgpt/openai

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Comment: @ewokx to be sure.....in order for me to run my code successfully I have to pay and buy more quota? Even for a simple program like that?

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure; but I suppose it is what you need to do, regardless of how simple/complex your script is.   Openai doesn't care of the complexity of your script.  Each access counts against the quota.

Comment: @ewokx I just bought $5 worth of credits and will generate a new API key and try and run it again. If it's a quota issue then I'll close this post.

Comment: just tried it and it works but i did receive a warning but works nonetheless. I corrected 1 syntax error and bought $5 of credit even though. i noticed no amount was subtracted once i ran the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.....at first i thought it was a quota issue but i changed "openai.ChatCompletion.create" to "openai.Completion.create" and problem solved. i guess I used the wrong method.

Comment: These are very different APIs. ChatCompletion is the new API and Completion will likely be deprecated, so not a solution.