# openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I recently obtained a free API key from OpenAI and attempted to use it in my script. However, I encountered the following error on my very first attempt:

`openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.`

I haven't used the API key before, so I'm puzzled by this error. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Using the API Key first time doesn't mean much.  It depends on how many queries you send to openai.   From what the error shows, you're sending too many queries.   That said, you should include your code to clarify whether or not you *are* sending more queries than you're allowed.  The other option is to upgrade your free to the pay plan.

Comment: Your current quota for API use may be exactly zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened to me when I sent a lot of prompts via the API. The rate limit is dependent on the amount of credits paid on your account and how long it has been since you have made your first payment.

According to the [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers?context=tier-free), there are different rate limits:

> Rate limits are measured in five ways: RPM (requests per minute), RPD (requests per day), TPM (tokens per minute), TPD (tokens per day), and IPM (images per minute). Rate limits can be hit across any of the options depending on what occurs first. For example, you might send 20 requests with only 100 tokens to the ChatCompletions endpoint and that would fill your limit (if your RPM was 20), even if you did not send 150k tokens (if your TPM limit was 150k) within those 20 requests.

This limit is bumped up if you upgrade your plan tier. The plans are as follows according to the [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers?context=tier-free):

| Tier | Qualification |
| --- | --- |
| Free | User must be in allowed geography |
| Tier 1 | $5 paid |
| Tier 2 | $50 paid and more than 7 days since first successful payment |
| Tier 3 | $100 paid and more than 7 days since first successful payment |
| Tier 4 | $250 paid and more than 14 days since first successful payment |
| Tier 5 | $1,000 paid and more than 30 days since first successful payment |

Depending on your Tier and the model you use, you can find your limits in the [OpenAI doucentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/usage-tiers?context=tier-free).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you registered an OpenAI account, but did not recharge the API or bind a bank card. Therefore, when the API is called for the first time, it will be detected that there is no balance in the account.
See details in this url: https://platform.openai.com/usage