# OpenAI: Error at Run failed You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. with credits

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm getting the following error when using playground or python in OpenAI.
I've credits ($65) and my account is Tier 1.

Run failed
You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to change the API KEY - Same Error.
Even at playground I get the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442646/openai-error-ratelimiterror-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please-check-your?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is the Plan you have subscribed to, other is the payment for the quota. They are 2 different things. You must pay for the tokens quota you use separately. Go to your account and look for the quota settings you should find the payment form for that feature. In other words, the plan you subscribed to and the usage quota are 2 different subscriptions that must be paid separately. Enrolling into a plan doesn't give you any extra quota except for the 5 USD bonus you have when you subscribe. When you consume those 5 USD you are asked to pay for more quota. The subscription is a monthly fee the quota can be paid when you deplete your allocation (the statistics dashboard will give you some more details about your tokens usage).