# why can't my langchain chatgpt app not bring me any results

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

I am trying to build a customized chatbot but I am getting an error :

> openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'

**Note:**
I have already set up billing in my openai account and put in 5 usd. I am able to use the assistant in the open ai playgrounds but not when I run my python code in terminal. Could someone kindly look at my code and review it.

This is my code :

```
import os
import sys

import openai
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain, RetrievalQA
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader, TextLoader
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.indexes.vectorstore import VectorStoreIndexWrapper
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

import constants

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY

# Enable to save to disk & reuse the model (for repeated queries on the same data)
PERSIST = False

query = None
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  query = sys.argv[1]

if PERSIST and os.path.exists("persist"):
  print("Reusing index...\n")
  vectorstore = Chroma(persist_directory="persist", embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings())
  index = VectorStoreIndexWrapper(vectorstore=vectorstore)
else:
  loader = TextLoader("data.txt") # Use this line if you only need data.txt
#   loader = DirectoryLoader("data/")
  if PERSIST:
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(vectorstore_kwargs={"persist_directory":"persist"}).from_loaders([loader])
  else:
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
  llm=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
  retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
)

chat_history = []
while True:
  if not query:
    query = input("Prompt: ")
  if query in ['quit', 'q', 'exit']:
    sys.exit()
  result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
  print(result['answer'])

  chat_history.append((query, result['answer']))
  query = None
```

contants.py only has my api key

I am still learning and any advise would mean alot to me.

I have put in 5 USD in my OpenAI playgrounds account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Comment: how does this page - [usage](https://platform.openai.com/usage) looks for you? add the screen snap.