# I got "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details" without reaching the limit

Tags: openai-api

I just created my first API key, and I want use the gpt-3.5-turbo model just for simple test, here is my code :

```
$url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey,
    ];

     // copy past from the tutorial https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests , I don't know what "temperature" is for..
    $data = [
        'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        'messages' => [
            ['role' => 'user', 'content' => 'Say this is a test!']
        ],
        "temperature" => "0.7"
    ]; 



    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);

    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);

    var_dump($decodedResponse);
```

I keep getting "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details." but accordingly to openAI, when using gpt-3.5-turbo model I should have 3 RPM. (request per minute) or 200 RPD (request per minute) for free and I'm far to reach the limit.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)

Comment: So I have to add my card credential even if I don't plan to reach the limit? If we have to, they should have made it mandatory.

Comment: Yes, correct. It is, actually, but it's not stated.

Comment: OK, you are right, it works now....