# RateLimitError on first OpenAI api request with a brand new new secret key

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have just created a new API key and pretty much immediately followed the instructions on this tutorial page: [QuickStart Tutorial - OpenAI API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart?context=python) and tried to send through the example on that page
... it failed with the following error:

```
RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}
```

... and I don't know why because I thought I should get $18 of trial credit. This chart on my "usage" page seems to imply that the trial credit has already expired, but how can that be? The API key is less than an hour old.

[image]

(I first signed up for ChatGPT a few months ago, but only for using it to chat to as an end-user -- is that relevant? Also note that there are a few very similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them have a definitive answer).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please)