# Axios error trying to contact openai api in React native

Tags: react-native, axios, openai-api

Error 401 trying to contact the openai api in React Native app.
I'm with android and I use the Expo Go application.

```
const sendMessage = async () => {
  const userMessage = { role: 'user', content: "Salut comment vas tu ?" };
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      CHAT_GPT_END_POINT,
      {
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages: [userMessage],
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
        },
      }
    );

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending message:', error);

  }
};
```

Here's my function that I call in a useEffect like this

```
useEffect(() => {
      sendMessage()
    }, []);
```

And here's the console log
`Error sending message: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]`

EDIT - Now I've the error code 429 Even if i use another ApiKey from another account...

Comment: The `401` error means *Invalid Authentication* (see [error codes](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors)).

Comment: Now I've the error code 429, even if I use another Api Key from another account...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898276/openai-api-error-429-you-exceeded-your-current-quota-please-check-your-plan-a)